# Calling method_getImplementation throws ExecutionEngineException on device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to implement swizzling from the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127453/how-to-port-method-getimplementation-and-method-setimplementation-to-monotou).  I have a example on [github](https://github.com/dbeattie71/HijackTest/tree/master/HiJackTest).  The full crash is [here](https://gist.github.com/dbeattie71/2baf841b2aec86c2a16f).

```
[DllImport("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib")]
extern static Func<IntPtr,IntPtr,IntPtr> method_getImplementation(IntPtr method);

delegate void CaptureDelegate(IntPtr block,IntPtr self,IntPtr uiView);

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(CaptureDelegate))]
static void MyCapture(IntPtr block, IntPtr self, IntPtr uiView)
{
}

static void HijackWillMoveToSuperView()
{
    var method = class_getInstanceMethod(new UIView().ClassHandle, new Selector("willMoveToSuperview:").Handle);

    original_impl = method_getImplementation(method);

    var block_value = new BlockLiteral();
    CaptureDelegate d = MyCapture;
    block_value.SetupBlock(d, null);
    var imp = imp_implementationWithBlock(ref block_value);
    method_setImplementation(method, imp);
}
```

The example works on the simulator but not on the device.  On the device,

```
 original_impl = method_getImplementation(method);
```

throws an `ExecutionEngineException`

> Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Func`3:wrapper_aot_native
>   (intptr&,intptr,intptr)' while running with --aot-only.

What do I need to do in order for this to be AOT compiled?  Or, is this an issue with calling method_getImplementation(method) on ARM64?  I've found some information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567869/observing-uiview-changes-crash).

> It seems like using an imp_implementationWithBlock crashes on arm64.

And more [here](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2014/a-story-about-swizzling-the-right-way-and-touch-forwarding/):

> Note the cast to objc_msgSend. While this (by luck) worked without
>   casting in the earlier days, this will probably crash your arm64 build
>   if you don’t cast this correctly, because the variable argument
>   casting specifications changed.

There is an example in objective-c [here](http://defagos.github.io/yet_another_article_about_method_swizzling/), where the architecture is checked and the behavior is different for 32 vs 64.  I'm wondering if I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value is an "IntPtr", not a "Func".

Comment: Did it use to be a Func?